# VB.NET: Getting DataGridView to Populate from Stored Procedure

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, bindingsource, tableadapter

I was just handed a VB.NET prototyping effort, and I'm not very experienced with VB.NET.

I had to create a stored procedure which returns a self-referential table in order. Once, I completed that I wanted to get a DataGridView to show the results.

Previously, my team has been doing a lot of this via the GUI designer of VB.NET so I don't have a ton of code to describe, unfortunately.

I was trying to follow their pattern which I will briefly describe here:

I have a DataGridView whose DataSource property points to a BindingSource. The BindingSource points to a DataSet. The editor for that DataSet calls a TableAdapter which gets the data from the stored procedure.

I previewed the data for the TableAdapter. The data is there. On frmMain's load the TableAdapter's Fill command is run.

Not seeing anything. And my hunch is that this is way too complex a process to be correct. Or maybe not. I did a lot of Google searches before I decided to bother you fine folks.

Answer (score 1):

Maby you did something like:

```
datagridview.datasource = ds
```

(That will show you an empty grid)

Try

```
datagridview.datasource = ds.tables(0)
```

Comment: This is quite delayed, but I'll give it a go.